# Prolog: Determine answers to Multiple Choice Question test where students' answers and grades are known

Tags: prolog

This is a prolog problem that I have to solve. I can't seem to find a starting point.

In a MCQ test where:

- each question has 4 choices [a,b,c,d]
- each question has only one correct answer (choice)
- there are 10 questions
- all questions have the same grade value (1 point, totalling 10 points)

4 students have taken this test and we have their grades:

- student1: [b, c, b, a, c, c, c, d, c, c] Grade: 7/10
- student2: [b, d, c, a, d, d, c, c, a, b] Grade: 6/10
- student3: [d, a, b, b, d, d, c, d, a, b] Grade: 5/10
- student4: [c, d, c, b, d, b, b, c, a, a] Grade: 3/10

From the informations above I need to write a prolog script that can determine the set of questions that are correct to get a 10/10 grade

Comment: What have you tried, what attempts did you make, what was not working with these? Hint: take a look at constraint-logic-programming.

Comment: This question has already been asked (and closed) before, but it was deleted ! There was another attempt here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59515775/is-there-anyone-who-can-help-me-on-prolog-exercise

Comment: For reference, this is a problem from a 2nd year Prolog course at [Université Pierre-Mendès-France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre_Mend%C3%A8s-France_University) which deals in social siences (Prolog for the social sciences? Not bad I say!) Looking for "sabine a donc décidé d'aider la chance" gives good effect on DuckDuckGo.

Comment: @joel76 It appears this one has also been deleted; do you know what the solution was?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can branch over the possible choices, and do bookkeeping on the score of the students. When we reach the end of the list, then the users need to have the correct score.

We thus can generate lists of choices with:

```
option(a).
option(b).
option(c).
option(d).

sequence(N, L) :-
    length(L, N),
    maplist(option, L).
```

For example for a sequence of two items, we get:

```
?- sequence(2, L).
L = [a, a] ;
L = [a, b] ;
L = [a, c] ;
L = [a, d] ;
L = [b, a] ;
L = [b, b] ;
L = [b, c] ;
L = [b, d] ;
L = [c, a] ;
L = [c, b] ;
L = [c, c] ;
L = [c, d] ;
L = [d, a] ;
L = [d, b] ;
L = [d, c] ;
L = [d, d].
```

Next we can make a predicate `mark/3` that calculates the score given the *hypothetical* correct sequence, and the sequence of a student. We thus need to implement something like:

```
mark([], [], 0).
mark(…, …, …) :-
    ….
```

I leave the implementation of `mark/3` as an exercise.

Then we thus can find the sequence of correct answers with:

```
correct(C) :-
    sequence(10, C),
    mark(C, [b, c, b, a, c, c, c, d, c, c], 7),
    mark(C, [b, d, c, a, d, d, c, c, a, b], 6),
    mark(C, [d, a, b, b, d, d, c, d, a, b], 5),
    mark(C, [c, d, c, b, d, b, b, c, a, a], 3).
```

You can later optimize the approach to an interleaved *generate-and-test* and not first generating sequences and then testing these. But I would first start with a simple solution that works.

When I implement this myself, there is exactly one solution. That solution has `b` as first answer.

Comment: A thousand thank you for your answer, it was really helpful I appreciate the fact that you didn't solve it all and left a part of the task for me. I actually couldn't leave a comment at first due to lack of reputation.

Comment: Also I found the answer to the problem thanks to your help I will be posting the commented code soon, and will of course credit you. Thanks

Comment: @AdelBouhraoua Could you post the answer? I am also interested in this program

Comment: I don't have it anymore unfortunately. I think I'll rewrite it for the sake of this post @Steak

Answer (score 1):

You can use **library(clfd)** and reification, everything is here : https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpfd-reification-predicates
(as already explain on another forum !)